# Bottom Bracket Tool

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

I am wanting to buy a tool that will remove bottom brackets on several bikes I have.  Will this one fit most modern ones? https://amzn.to/2NEsjU7

Comment: 'THE' BB-tool does not exist in the way 'THE' BB does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

BBs are very widespread and there's several styles out there. Do you know what types of cranksets/BBs you have? The link you posted is for square taper BBs. Those tools will not be compatible with modern hollow spindle cranks.

[Here](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-tool-selection-threaded-and-thread-together) is a Park Tool link to a guide on identifying your BB type. You may end up needing a different tool for each of your bikes.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you linked to will work on 20 tooth splined cartridge bottom brackets. That's the standard used by Shimano on their cartridge bottom brackets. Some other bottom brackets may be different.

You'll have to check the bottom brackets on your particular bikes. If any bikes have external threaded BBs, or non-cartridge "loose ball bearing' or are from a different manufacturer you'll need  different tool.

Check out [Park Tool's BB tool page](https://www.parktool.com/category/crank-bottom-bracket) for an idea of all the different tool types.